# C# Gui setting control.Enabled to false fires OnClick event?

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, events

For some really weird reason when i set the .Enabled property to false on a simple text box on a small GUI, it fires a radio buttons OnClick event and its causing lots of problems.

I have breakpointed the txtBox.Enabled = false; and after stepping over OR into it i jump straight to the OnClick event of the radio button control

Here is the call stack as that happened:

> TestGUI.exe!TestGUI.frmMain.radiobuttonClicked(object sender = {Text = "Download Single Episode" Checked = true}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 67 C#
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x70 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x27 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnEnter(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) + 0x3e bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyEnter() + 0x20 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl() + 0x195 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.AssignActiveControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control value = {Text = "Download Single Episode" Checked = true}) + 0x54 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, bool originator = false) + 0x76 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.SetActiveControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control value = {Text = "Download Single Episode" Checked = true}) + 0x73 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.SetActiveControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl) + 0x33 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActiveControl.set(System.Windows.Forms.Control value) + 0x5 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Select(bool directed, bool forward) + 0x1b bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl, bool forward, bool tabStopOnly, bool nested, bool wrap) + 0x7b bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control ctl, bool forward, bool tabStopOnly, bool nested, bool wrap) + 0x4a bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextIfFocused() + 0x61 bytes 
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enabled.set(bool value) + 0x42 bytes

What the hell?

It wouldn't have anything to do with the way i subscribe to the events would it?

`this.radioBtnMultipleDownload.Click += radiobuttonClicked;`
 `this.radioBtnSingleDownload.Click += radiobuttonClicked;`
 `this.radioCustomUrl.Click += radiobuttonClicked;`

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem. One article is: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/77fbec3b-1f63-42e1-a200-19b261b63794/the-radiobutton-clicked-event-is-fired-without-the-radio-button-beeing-clicked-?forum=winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second to last line of your call stack:

> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextIfFocused()
>   + 0x61 bytes

Apparently, `RadioButton` fires `OnClicked` on its `OnEnter`, which fires from its `UpdateFocusedControl`, which happens because this is the next control.  You could try to call `Control.Focus()` on something else that you want to gain focus before the `TextBox` is disabled, so that `SelectNextIfFocused()` won't do anything, ie:

```
dummyTextBox.Focus();
txtBox.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Very nice this did fix it. I added a random text box and focused that before i did the .Enabled = false, however is there a more elegant solution? I don't really have any other controls i can focus apart from another radio button! >_<

Comment: @Daniel, Not that I know of off hand... I've seen a couple people recommend having a non-visible control that you could focus specifically for this, but haven't ever really done that myself... things like this, I've always had another control (usually a 'submit' button or something) that I could focus.

Comment: Ah yep i focused the OK button and that worked a charm, however is there a way to unfocus the button after? Or does something always need to have focus?

Comment: I think something always needs to have focus, but I'm not 100% sure on the subtleties of how that works.  You could play around with TabIndex too (that's what determines the "Next" control), and come up with a more elegant solution that way.  Basically, what do you want to happen if the user hits Enter or Tab if they were in the text box and you disable it?

Comment: I'm disabling the controls after they have filled in some information and then clicked OK, otherwise they could still modify the entries and make it look wrong. I have made another button which i was intending on doing anyway to stop the process, so i'll focus that and it'll all be good! :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox` has an `EnabledChanged` property.  Are you sure you're not doing this somewhere?

```
this.textBox1.EnabledChanged += radiobuttonClicked;
```

Another possibility is that you've hooked into the TextBox's `LostFocus` event, which will fire if the TextBox has the focus when you disable it.  Or maybe you've hooked into some other control's `GotFocus` event, which would also fire if the TextBox has the focus when you disable it.

Comment: Judging by the stack trace it's not related to that event, but a weird side-effect of the focus being moved to the next control because the one it was on became disabled.

Comment: I just did a entire solution ctrl + f for "EnabledChanged" and nothing came up, so i guess it's something else. This is very weird and frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Quick note - not really a solution, but providing some hints: I just ran into the same problem in a quite static dialog without any EnabledChanged handlers or calls, in fact even without any event handlers assigned to my RadioButtons. And no data binding or other black magic.

It seems that SelectNextIfFocused hit those buttons inside ShowDialog merely because they were first in the control's tab order, albeit nested inside a TableLayoutPanel inside a GroupBox. This resulted in the wrong RadioButton being checked. And since the dialog's tab order was askew, I changed that first.

This seems to have fixed the problem for me. But you may as well try something similar, i.e. insert some empty label among your controls to have it receive the events resulting from SelectNextIfFocused.